# How to make React js Page Responsive?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I am stuck with a problem, I am using `argon creative Tim` and `ReactStrap` for making this UI, It's working fine, but when am trying to view it on Mobile View it is not working as expected.

image is not responsive when i want to view on mobile view
[image: img not responsive]

> login.jsx

Below I share my all code for making UI. let me know if you have any question.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { Button, Row, Col, FormGroup, Form, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Label } from "reactstrap";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";

import "./Login.css";

const Login = ({ user }) => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className="section section-hero section-shaped">
                <div className="shape shape-style-1 shape-primary">
                    <span className="span-150"></span>
                    <span className="span-50"></span>
                    <span className="span-50"></span>
                    <span className="span-75"></span>
                    <span className="span-100"></span>
                    <span className="span-75"></span>
                    <span className="span-50"></span>
                    <span className="span-100"></span>
                    <span className="span-50"></span>
                    <span className="span-100"></span>
                </div>
                <div className="outer">
                    <div className="inner" style={{ width: "450px", height: "450px", marginBottom:"80px" }}>
                        <h3>{user} Log In</h3>
                        <br />
                        <Form role="form" method="POST">
                            <FormGroup className="mb-3">
                                <Label for="email">Email</Label>
                                <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                                    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                        <InputGroupText>
                                            <i className="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                                        </InputGroupText>
                                    </InputGroupAddon>
                                    <Input type="email"
                                 />
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="password">Password</Label>
                                <InputGroup className="input-group-alternative">
                                    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                                        <InputGroupText>
                                            <i className="fas fa-key"></i>
                                        </InputGroupText>
                                    </InputGroupAddon>
                                    <Input
                                        type="password"
                                        autoComplete="off"
                                        required="required"
                            
                                    />
                                </InputGroup>
                            </FormGroup>

                            <div className="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox">
                                <input
                                    className="custom-control-input"
                                    id=" customCheckLogin"
                                    type="checkbox"
                                />
                                <label
                                    className="custom-control-label"
                                    htmlFor=" customCheckLogin"
                                >
                                    <span>Remember me</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div className="text-center">
                                <Button
                                    className="my-4"
                                    color="primary"
                                    type="button"
                                    onClick={login}
                                >
                                    Sign in
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </Form>
                        <Row className="mt-3">
                            <Col xs="6">
                                <a
                                    className="text-light"
                                    href="#"
                                    onClick={e => e.preventDefault()}
                                >
                                    <small>Forgot password?</small>
                                </a>
                            </Col>
                            {bool ? <Col className="text-right" xs="6">
                                <NavLink exact to='./signup' className="text-light">Create new account</NavLink>
                            </Col>
                                : <Col className="text-right" xs="6">
                                    <NavLink exact to='./vendorsignup' className="text-light">Create new account</NavLink>
                                </Col>}
                        </Row>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default Login;
```

> Login.css

```
.outer {
  height: 100vh;
  background-position: fixed;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form-group label {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;

  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}
.form-group input {
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.6);
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: inherit;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}
.signinp {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
}
.whiteinput {
  background-color: white !important;
}

/* .form-group input:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.form-group input:focus {
  border: 1px solid black;
} */
.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: left;
}
.inner {
  width: 450px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgb(34 35 58 / 20%);
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.outer .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #167bff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.outer h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #167bff;
}
```

Comment: What isn't working? Please be more specific about your issue.

Comment: its not responsive in mobile view

Comment: What does that mean? Generally your app is either responsive (in any screen), or it isn't. Something as simple as `width: 100%` can make an element "responsive". Could you create a running codesandbox of your code so we can see and debug it live?

Comment: use @media and the width you need and put your css init

Comment: Using media queries and special breakpoints alone doesn't magically make your UI responsive. These are a couple tools in all of CSS that help make your UI elements responsive. I suggest you research "mobile first design" to gain a better understanding of what responsive web design is and how you can apply different solutions to different UI responsive problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think the single most important thing you can do if you want to start working with "intuitive" responsive design is to update your box-model to use the `border-box`.

[Box Sizing CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Add the following to your CSS

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

This will size your containers to match what you specify in CSS, with the padding on the inside and the margins outside. I am still amazed this isn't the default. All projects should implement this fix/change.

To specifically address the responsive issue with the login modal, set the `max-width` to a static value, i.e. the `450px` and set the width to a relative value, i.e. `90%`.

```
.inner {
  max-width: 550px; // <-- static max value
  width: 90%;       // <-- dynamic relative value
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgb(34 35 58 / 20%);
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit how-to-make-react-js-page-responsive]

Play around and resize the view window, and then test out toggling the responsive view in the preview window.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you aren't using any code to have responsiveness in your App.
You can use the @media rule. Also good practice is to use CSS Grid system.
There are also CSS Frameworks like Bootstrap which have their implementation of responsive grid system which is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Its not related to Reactjs, you will have to modify your css code, for that you can use CSS media queries to target the screen/mobile sizes as per your need.

Example :

```
/* For screen size more than 400px */
@media screen and (min-width: 400px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }
}

/* For screen size less than 600px */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lavender;
  }
}
```

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

You can also try bootstrap, foundation, materialize css libraries which has ready made classes for responsive screen sizes.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_stacked_to_horizontal.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to make changes to CSS so that the DOM elements rendered on screen look good on different screen sizes

Some things which you can explore are

1. Media queries
2. Material UI Grid
3. Bootstrap's breakpoints